# how to get all the contiguous interval of all IDs in a relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, intervals

So my relation is simple: relation (ID, Date), which ID is not unique and not necessarily in any order. Each ID has a date (same ID can have the same date). My problem is to find the longest interval between a date and its NEXT date of all IDs.

So if the table is like this:

```
 ID     |   Date
--------+------------
    100 | 2015-06-20
    100 | 2015-01-21
    100 | 2016-04-23
```

the expected output will be

```
ID      |   interval
--------+------------
    100 | (2016-04-23 - 2015-06-20)
```

or if all date the ID has are the same:

```
 ID     |   Date
--------+------------
    100 | 2016-04-23
    100 | 2016-04-23
    100 | 2016-04-23
```

the expected output should be

```
ID      |   interval
--------+------------
    100 |        0
```

this is for a single ID, in my relation, there are 100 IDs are together

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will be useful for you:

```
select t.id,
       case
         when t.lower != t.upper then '(' || t.lower || ' - ' || t.upper || ')'
         else '0' end
from (select
             r.id,
             min(r.date) as lower,
             max(r.date) as upper
      from relation r
      group by r.id) t;
```

We use a subquery to find lower and upper boundaries for each `ID`. After that we check lower and upper boundaries when they equals make formatted string else out zero.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
 WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT id, _date, lead_date, EXTRACT(epoch FROM age(lead_date,_date))/(3600*24) AS age
     FROM
        (
          SELECT *,  lead(_date) over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY _date ) lead_date
            from table_log
            order by id, _date
        ) as z
    WHERE lead_date IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY 4 DESC
 )
SELECT DISTINCT id ,
   (SELECT age FROM x WHERE x.id = t1.id ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1)
  FROM table_log t1
```

Here i have used [windows function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to get the next date to determine the duration between 2 entries. with [Postgres Recursive](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) query you can re-use the original query with windows function.

I have used DISTINCT from the log table, but you can also directly use the table where you store the IDs.